# Angular2,(change)event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm new with Angular and struggling with event binding...

I set `(change)`event in `mdInput` with `[(ngModel)]`and`mdAutocomplete`, but it doesn't fire....it used to work properly in `md-select` without `mdAutocomplete`.

Can't `(change)`event  work together with `mdAutocomplete` or not in `mdInput`?

any codes I lack?

```
<md-input-container class=middle-class>
                <input mdInput required placeholder="荷主" [(ngModel)]="detail.ownerTx" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="detail.changeOwner($event)"
                  [mdAutocomplete]="autoTxt">
              </md-input-container>
              <md-autocomplete #autoTxt="mdAutocomplete">
                <md-option *ngFor="let owner of detail.owners" [value]="owner.ownerTx">{{ owner.ownerTx }}</md-option>
              </md-autocomplete>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `(ngModelChange)` instead of change

```
 <input mdInput required placeholder="荷主" [(ngModel)]="detail.ownerTx" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="detail.changeOwner($event)"
                  [mdAutocomplete]="autoTxt">
```

Comment: oha, it works!! thank you!! will check this answer as best one in a sec.

Comment: will do in a sec.

Comment: figuratively speaking buddy,I marked now plz make sure.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: ya i understand! marking answer and upvoting are different. you should see an up arrow next to answer